# How do I implement "sloppy swiping" to allow the iOS sliding pop gesture to work from the middle and not just the edge?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, gesture, swipe-gesture

In iOS 7 and later you can pull from the left side of the screen to the right to pop back to the previous view controller, but it only works from the side of the screen. [Josh Ginter wrote about sloppy swiping](http://thenewsprint.co/2014/04/16/sloppy-swiping/), but I'm confused how one would actually implement it and I can't seem to find any resources out there about it.

Comment: Why do you want to go against the gesture people expect? Just add your own gesture...

Comment: @Wain Read the article I posted. It doesn't conflict with the "expected gesture" whatsoever.